# Locating YouTube dependencies

Tags: java, youtube

Trying to compile to YouTube Java API samples. Missing the package

com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube

I can't find it anywhere from googling or Github. Anyone who's used the YouTube Java API maybe can offer input for compiling the sample project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search for that package name turned up the [YouTube Data API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3#sample), which contains [that class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.html). I'm really surprised you didn't find this from googling since those are literally the first and second results I found on Google when I searched for `com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube`.

Have you downloaded this API and added it to your classpath?